# python list must have all values comma separated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make sure argument passed as list has distinct values and comma separated otherwise throw error for any other delimiter like tab, space , semi colon anything.

Case 1-

```
input -> ['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-02-01','2015-03-01']
output -> ['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01','2015-03-01']
```

Case 2-

```
input -> ['2015-01-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-03-01']
output -> raise exception - please enter comma separated list.
```

Comment: The input of case 2 will itself throw a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: do you mean you're going to process the input as string?

Comment: Please post actually executable code that nails down your problem. Show the function that you are passing the arguments to and where that argument comes from.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string representing a Python list literal manually? Why? This sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Bazingaa - you are right , case2 throws error.

Comment: I am trying to validate user input for a process and want to make sure they give input in correct format - comma separated and distinct. The process takes input as list.

Comment: @sandy No, the process takes a string containing a list *literal* as input; that's a very big, and very important, distinction to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just assuming the expected outcome and input from the comments and answers posted earlier

```
import re
string_list = ["['2015-01-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-03-01']",
                      "['2015-01-01';'2015-02-01' '2015-02-01';'2015-03-01']",
                      "['2015-01-01';'2015-02-01'    '2015-02-01';'2015-03-01']",
                      "['2015-01-01','2015-02-01','2015-02-01','2015-03-01']"
                     ]
for i in string_list:
    if re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'[;*&\t\s]{1,}",i):
        print('invalid') # raise excpetion here
    else:
        print(set(i[1:-1].replace("'",'').split(',')))
```

Output:

```
invalid
invalid
invalid
set(['2015-03-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01'])
```

The valid output would be of type set which can be converted to list if required using `list()`

Comment: `set([';']).intersection(set(inList))` what if the `str` contains a semicolon in a non-delimiter part of the list-literal expression?

Comment: I think you're sticking to the `;` a bit too literally as the OP had stated "for any other delimiter like tab, space , semi colon anything" I mean, what they're looking for is basically a module that will just always return the right data, or at least raise an exception if it's the wrong data. Which would be great, and I'd love to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is little information to go on. 
Here is a simple solution to what i think it is you are trying to ask:

```
l1 = []

while True:
    user_ = input("> ")

    if user_ == "exit":
        break

    if user_ in l1:
        print("already exists")
    if user_ not in l1:

        l1.append(user_)
        print(l1)


print(l1)
```

Basically this will prevent the user from inputting the same thing twice.
You do not need to worry about the list being in an incorrect format. Lists in python will always have comma separation when user inputs.

If you would like to make sure the user is inputting string in a specific format IE in date form yyyy/mm/dd. You would just need to add another conditional to check that. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the method I would use, that way you're guaranteed a list at the end, the only downfall is each entry would need to be done one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines could cleanup user input, but it will always have the potential for someone to put something unexpected in.

I would take each value separately and append them to a list, myself.

```
inList = "['2015-01-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-02-01';'2015-03-01']"

delimiters = [",", ";", "\t", "\n", " "]
rem = ["[", "]", '"', "'", " "]
out = []
for delimiter in delimiters:
  if delimiter in inList:
    for r in rem:
      if delimiter == r :break
      inList = inList.replace(r, '')
    out = inList.split(delimiter)
    break

print(out)
```